# Possible Visual Studio c++ compiler bug ? Trouble with template template non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-bug

## New question

### edit

This bug seems to be the same as [this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773294/msvc-says-template-class-doesnt-match-template-template-parameter-but-it-doeshttps://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773294/msvc-says-template-class-doesnt-match-template-template-parameter-but-it-does):

MSVC rejects the following code:

```
template <template <typename T, typename T::mytype x> class X>
struct z
{};

template <typename T, typename T::mytype xx>
struct x
{};

z<x> zz;
```

> error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'x' does not match the     template parameter list for template parameter 'X'
>
> But class template x has the same set of template parameters as parameter X does.

Hell! This bug report is from april 2012 ?!

With

> Status: Closed as Deferred

:(

*Microsoft*, I am disappoint TT

### edit of edit

In my case (below), I can hack my way to do what I want, but it's ugly:

```
//Library code
struct Boundary {
    double sup, inf;
};

template <
    class UserBoundaries, 
    template <size_t, bool...> class LocalInfo, 
    size_t hack>
struct Space_LocalParameters : LocalInfo<hack> {};


//User code
struct Boundaries_Problem7 {
    Boundary b1, b2, b3;
};

template <size_t, bool...>
struct LocalInfo_Problem7 {};

template <size_t hack, bool... args>
struct Problem7_Functions 
: Space_LocalParameters < Boundaries_Problem7, LocalInfo_Problem7, hack, args...> {};

int main() {}
```

Use:

```
//Compute the offset of member b2 in Boundaries_Problem7
const size_t hack = (size_t)(&((Boundaries_Problem7*)0)->b2);

if (...)
    problem.functions[k].SetFunction(&Problem7_Functions<hack, true, false>::f);
else if (...) 
    problem.functions[k].SetFunction(&Problem7_Functions<hack, false, true>::f);
else problem.functions[k].SetFunction(&Problem7_Functions<hack, false, false>::f);

//Later in that function
if (boundary_Inf) {
    value += this->points[0].coef 
             * ((Boundary*)((char*)&domain.boundaries + hack))->inf;
}
if (boundary_Sup) {
    value += this->points[N-1].coef 
             * ((Boundary*)((char*)&domain.boundaries + hack))->sup;
}
```

Is the compiler allowed to change the offset of a member during optimization ?

### end of edit

## New question

The following compiles fine on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be088e06861f9349

```
//Library code
struct Boundary {};

template <
    class UserBoundaries, 
    template <Boundary UserBoundaries::*> class LocalInfo, 
    Boundary UserBoundaries::*m_ptr>
struct Space_LocalParameters : LocalInfo<m_ptr> {};


//User code
struct Boundaries_Problem7 {
    Boundary b1, b2, b3;
};

template <Boundary Boundaries_Problem7::*m_ptr>
struct LocalInfo_Problem7 {};

template <Boundary Boundaries_Problem7::*ptr>
struct Problem7_Functions 
: Space_LocalParameters < Boundaries_Problem7, LocalInfo_Problem7, ptr> {}; // <-- C3201


int main() {}
```

But visual studio 2013 gives me this error:

> error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'LocalInfo_Problem7' does not match the  template parameter list for template parameter 'LocalInfo'

Is this a VS compiler bug ?
Or is my code wrong ?

I wrote a bug report here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/933984/c-visual-studio-2013-compiler-bug-template-template-pointer-to-member-issue

If this is a bug, how could I get this to work ?

Thanks for your help.

## Old question

I have some troubles with a somewhat complex template "typedef".

Simplifying the problem as much as possible, I came up with this:

```
template <class A, template <A*> class B, A* ptr>
struct Foo : B<ptr> {};

template <class, class AA, template <AA*> class BB, AA* ptr>
using Bar = Foo<AA, BB, ptr>;                           //  <-- C3201
```

visual studio 2013 gives me:
error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'BB' does not match the template parameter list for template parameter 'B'

I don't see what is wrong.

`Foo<AA, BB, ptr>` "expands to" `template <class AA, template <AA*> class BB, AA* ptr> struct Foo : BB<ptr> {}`

In theory, if we define the follwing (I did not actually try to compile the following):

```
class MyClass {} myClass_instance;
template <MyClass*> class MyTemplateClass {};
```

Then

```
Bar<whatever, MyClass, MyTemplateClass, &myClass_instance>
```

should be an alias for

```
Foo<MyClass, MyTemplateClass, &myClass_instance> : MyTemplateClass<&myClass_instance>
```

This looks ok to me.

Curiously, the two following variations compile fine:

1/ Changing `template <A*>` and `template <AA*>` with `template <Z*>`

```
class Z;

template <class A, template <Z*> class B, A* ptr>
struct Foo : B<ptr> {};

template <class, class AA, template <Z*> class BB, AA* ptr>
using Bar = Foo<AA, BB, ptr>;
```

This workaround let my program run fine, but this defeat the purpose my template approach.

Or 2/ Removing the first template parameter of Bar

```
template <class A, template <A*> class B, A* ptr>
struct Foo : B<ptr> {};

template <class AA, template <AA*> class BB, AA* ptr>
using Bar = Foo<AA, BB, ptr>;
```

So what is the mismatch mentioned by the compiler?

How comes removing the first template parameter of Bar solves the problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It [compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea99dff238d72b4b) with GCC and Clang, so maybe it's a bug in VS? But note that I **defined** `MyTemplateClass` as it **does fail** when it is only declared (as you showed above!). Maybe you can provide a minimal but complete example?

Comment: @DanielFrey Yes MyTemplateClass should be defined. I edited y question and added "{}". Thanks you for the link, I will use this to test for VS strange behaviors in the futur. So this seems to be a VS bug :(

Comment: Looks like [this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773294/msvc-says-template-class-doesnt-match-template-template-parameter-but-it-doeshttps://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773294/msvc-says-template-class-doesnt-match-template-template-parameter-but-it-does)?

Comment: @Praetorian Yes. This seems to be the same bug. Thank you.

Comment: What is VS in title? Would save time of non-MS people to tell this in early explanation of question.

Comment: @TõnuSamuel Visual Studio, the product that contains Microsoft's C++ compiler.

Comment: @TõnuSamuel Regarding your edited comment, you don't expect people to explain what GCC is, you don't expect people to explain what Clang is, you shouldn't expect people to explain what VS is. You happened to not know. That's fine. Now you do. Problem solved. :)